# Async.js eachSeries without stopping on error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an array I need to process asynchronously in order. If one of them failed, I need to continue processing the rest but I need to keep track of that error so I can do something at the end of the the entire process.

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async), it looks like this feature isn't really built into `eachSeries`. It seems like I'd have to call `callback()` on every task, indicating that it's always successful and keep track of the errors on the side myself. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

keeping track of the error yourself here isn't necessarily a bad thing:

```
var errors = [];
async.eachSeries([1,2,3], function(data, cb) {
  if(some_error_case) {
    errors.push(data);
  }
  cb(null);
}, function(data) {
  console.log('errors happened: ', errors);
});
```

always call `cb(null)` even when there's an error, otherwise it will stop the loop prematurely. Then push any errors into the `errors` array and deal with them in the callback at the end.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'll do. I call `cb()` instead, it looks like `null` isn't really required.

Comment: @pixelfreak - To each their own - I like sending null to explicitly point out that there is no error although either case is fine.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, `reflect` and `reflectAll` have been added to *async*, to cover this scenario.

Example (from official docs):

```
async.parallel([
    async.reflect(function(callback) {
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    }),
    async.reflect(function(callback) {
        // do some more stuff but error ...
        callback('bad stuff happened');
    }),
    async.reflect(function(callback) {
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    })
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    // values
    // results[0].value = 'one'
    // results[1].error = 'bad stuff happened'
    // results[2].value = 'two'
});
```

Docs:

[Async Reflect](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#reflect)